# Female to female jumper wires

Tags: wire, jumper, wire-terminals

Where are female to female jumper wires used? They only have provision to allow other wires to be plugged into so cannot be used on breadboards. So, practically, where are they used?

Answer (score 2):

Not on breadboards, that is true, but you can use them very well to connect to single pins of pin headers. For example the Raspberry Pi offers a 40-pin header, and the female jumper wires are a very convenient way to prope these pins.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One use is to jumper between male headers found on circuit boards.